# For loop stops iterating after first item in listbox

Tags: c#, multithreading, for-loop, iteration

I have a `for` loop that I want (for every item in a `ListBox`) to execute a method.

What happening now is the first item is being selected, the method is being executed, but then it doesn't select the second item, it just sits there.

Can you help?

This is how my `for` loop looks:

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBox8.Items.Count; i++) {
    listBox8.SetSelected(i, true);
    listBox8.SelectedIndex = 0;

    Thread t = new Thread(signinmobile);
    t.Start();
    CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls = false;
}
```

And here is my sub:

```
public void signinmobile()
{
    string yourString = listBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();
    string[] strArray = yourString.Split(':');

    System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    string postData = "authenticity_token=401538d41ace8f334c3d&username=" + strArray[0] + "&password=" + strArray[1] + "";
    CookieContainer tempCookies = new CookieContainer();
    UTF8Encoding encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
    byte[] byteData = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    HttpWebRequest postReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://mobile.twitter.com/session");
    postReq.Method = "POST";
    postReq.KeepAlive = true;
    postReq.CookieContainer = tempCookies;
    postReq.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    postReq.Referer = "https://mobile.twitter.com/session";
    postReq.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; ru; rv:1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/4.0 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)";
    postReq.ContentLength = byteData.Length;

    Stream postreqstream = postReq.GetRequestStream();
    postreqstream.Write(byteData, 0, byteData.Length);
    postreqstream.Close();
    HttpWebResponse postresponse = default(HttpWebResponse);

    postresponse = (HttpWebResponse)postReq.GetResponse();
    tempCookies.Add(postresponse.Cookies);
    StreamReader postreqreader = new StreamReader(postresponse.GetResponseStream());

    string accountstatus = postreqreader.ReadToEnd();

    webBrowser1.DocumentText = accountstatus;

    if (accountstatus.Contains("Sign in information is not correct"))
    {
        listBox9.Items.Add(listBox8.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r");
        while (listBox8.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            listBox8.Items.Remove(listBox8.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        listBox2.Items.Add(listBox8.SelectedItem.ToString() + "\r");

        while (listBox8.SelectedItems.Count > 0)
        {
            listBox8.Items.Remove(listBox8.SelectedItems[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why listBox8.SetSelected(i, true); then listBox8.SelectedIndex = 0;?  I mean is there something else happening in there?

Comment: Are you using the list selection in the method signinmobile? if yes then can you please post that code? It does not look thread safe to me

Comment: @rfmodulator I just put both those lines to make sure it selects the first item because without them my for loop just stood idle not doing anything. And once the method is completed it removes the selecteditem.

Comment: @GETah I edited it and added the sub code

Comment: @GETah, of course it's not thread safe, he had to disable CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls for it to run in the first place. :)

Comment: @user1017524 This code, not thread safe, can end up in an undeterministic state, please see my answer below

Comment: @GETah Oh alright, also mind helping me with the issue about the loop though?

Comment: Still need help, none of the solutions are working :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following line always selecting the first item for each loop cycle

```
listBox8.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

I believe you can remove this line at all because previous one (`listBox8.SetSelected(i, true);`) already does selection

**EDIT:** Since question was updated

I feel that here is exception may occur. Add `try/catch(Exception ex)` block around `signinmobile` method call and say us whether eny exception was handled.

BTW, Why you are running method in an other thread? Looks like there is thread sync issue so if list contains more then two items multiple threads would run and removing items in list, and then call to `SetSelected` fails since it cached index value `i` which currently not exists since some thread already removed item... So run all in single thread or do `t.Join()` after `t.Start()` so main thread would wait until working thread is done and them continue next loop cycle.

Comment: I forgot to say that the sub removes the selecteditem after its been called.

Comment: How you are removing the item from the list box? SHow please code

Comment: I feel that here is exception may occur, because you are removing Item inside a foreach loop. add `try/catch(Exception ex)` block around `signinmobile` method call and say us whether eny exception was handled

Comment: Hey, the first exception thrown was 'Index out of bounds of array', then 'Object reference not Set to the instance of an object' all referring to the listbox(es) no doubt

Comment: I am using a for loop not a foreach loop ._.

Comment: sorry overloked that, so on which line exception occur? Run in debugger to see line

Comment: After removing it I got two Object reference not set errors and it never iterated to the second object.

Comment: It depends, it lets the user upload as many items as they want

Comment: Why you running method in an other thread? Looks like there are thread sync issue so if list contains more then two items multiple threads wuld run and remove items in list, and then call to `SetSelected` fails since it cached index value `i` wjich currently not exists since some thread already removed item... So run all in single thread or do `t.Join()` after `t.Start()`

Comment: Hmm it seemed to work but its not doing it for the first and second item. I uploaded a file with three items and the third one never got used :/

Comment: change for loop condition from `<` to `<=`

Comment: Nope :/ it still only 'Joined' the first two, not the third.

Comment: YOu need to debug and see why loop exit before third item, looks like i is greater than exit condition

Comment: I changed my code around, added a label to display the current count of the items in the listbox, and used that instead of the items.count in my for loop. Now it 'joins' all items, but then I get an error that says: InvalidArgument=Value of '0' is not valid for 'SelectedIndex'.
Parameter name: SelectedIndex on 
                listBox8.SelectedIndex = 0;

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5382/discussion-between-user1017524-and-sll)

Answer (score 1):

You set the selected index again to 0. That is the first item. So every iteration of the loop it stays at the first item.

Comment: I forgot to say that the sub removes the selecteditem after its been called.

Answer (score 1):

You're resetting `SelectedIndex` to `0` each time, so it follows that it won't move forward... just remove that line.

Comment: I forgot to say that the sub removes the selecteditem after its been called.

Answer (score 0):

The above answers have well caught the `listBox8.SelectedIndex = 0;` issue.

I just want to comment on the `signinmobile` method.

Gurus, correct me if I am wrong but if this method is using the list box selection to do some background work in the created thread then the whole thing won't work! By the time the created thread spins and starts working on the selected item `string yourString = listBox8.SelectedItem.ToString();`
the parent thread will change the selection in the `for` loop `listBox8.SetSelected(i, true);` which might disturb the previously created worker thread. 
To make sure this is thread safe, I would extract the item to work on on the `for` loop and pass it as a string to the worker thread. This way you are 100% sure only one thread accesses the list box and changes its selection.

Suggested fix

```
for(int i = 0; i < listBox8.Items.Count; i++) {
    Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(signinmobile));
    t.Start(listBox8.Items[i].ToString());
}
// Now that you started all thread to work on all items
// You can cleanup the list box safely

public void signinmobile(string parameter) {
    string yourString = parameter; // No need to access the shared list
    //...
    if (accountstatus.Contains("Sign in information is not correct")) {
       listBox9.Items.Add(parameter + "\r");
       // No need to access the shared list to remove the item
    } else  {
       listBox2.Items.Add(parameter + "\r");
       // No need to access the shared list to remove the item
    }
}
```

Comment: Im working with a for loop not a foreach or should I switch to a foreach?

Comment: @user1017524 Just edited my code to work with a for loop instead. Hope this helps

Comment: Nope  I still need help with the issue. Thanks but I think your answer might be a too complex for what I am doing :/